# (SAS) Removing duplicates during concatenation

Tags: sas

I'm using the following data step to concatenate multiple observations' values into one variable:

```
data Data_PreFinal;
set work.reasons;
by Number;
length Changes $4000.;
retain Changes;
if first.Number then Changes = EndoReason;
else Changes = catx(', ', Changes, EndoReason);
if last.Number then output;
run;
```

For example, I would like to ensure that if the dataset Reasons looks like this:

```
Number    EndoReason
1         Bucket1
1         Bucket2
1         Bucket1
1         Bucket3
1         Bucket2
1         Bucket2
2         Bucket2
2         Bucket2
2         Bucket1
2         Bucket2
```

that the resulting dataset, Data_PreFinal, looks like this:

```
Number    EndoReason
1         Bucket1, Bucket2, Bucket3
2         Bucket2, Bucket1
```

instead of listing out all the duplicate values in the EndoReason variable.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a search in the current Changes string for the specific row's value and only concatenate if it doesn't already exist.  The `index` function is the one to use and I've also modified your code slightly to use `call catx` instead of `catx` (I think it's neater in these situations).

```
data reasons;
input Number EndoReason $;
datalines;
1         Bucket1
1         Bucket2
1         Bucket1
1         Bucket3
1         Bucket2
1         Bucket2
2         Bucket2
2         Bucket2
2         Bucket1
2         Bucket2
;
run;

data Data_PreFinal;
set work.reasons;
by Number;
length Changes $4000.;
retain Changes;
if first.Number then call missing(Changes);
if not index(Changes,trim(EndoReason)) then call catx(', ', Changes, EndoReason);
if last.Number then output;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Friend!, maybe it could be useful to delete duplicate observations first. For example:

```
data reasons;
    input Number EndoReason : $30.;
    datalines;
1         Bucket1
1         Bucket2
1         Bucket1
1         Bucket3
1         Bucket2
1         Bucket2
2         Bucket2
2         Bucket2
2         Bucket1
2         Bucket2
;

*Only eliminate duplicates;
proc sort data=reasons out=reasons_nodup nodup;
    by Number EndoReason;
run;

data Data_PreFinal;
    set work.reasons_nodup;
    by Number;
    length Changes $4000.;
    retain Changes;
    if first.Number then Changes = EndoReason;
    else Changes = catx(', ', Changes, EndoReason);
    if last.Number then output;

    drop EndoReason;
    rename Changes = EndoReason;
run;
```

Good luck!